# why does $_GET not work in header-function?

Tags: php, html, variables, get, global-variables

I already have a question with this issue but a further question belonging `$_GET` and header-function:

I have a multilingual site. When calling a page that does not exist, `.htaccess` will refer to `404.php` in the root directory.

The `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

That `404.php` in the root direction simply looks at which default language is set by a `SESSION` or `COOKIE` and refers to the language subdirectory `/language/404.php`

The root `404.php` looks like that:

```
include_once "scripts/pref_language.php";

if (isset ($_GET['uri']) ){
    $get = $_GET['uri'];

    header("Location: /$pref_language/404.php?uri=$get");
    exit;
}

$url = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

header("Location: /$pref_language/404.php?uri=$url");
```

Refered to the language subdirectory, the posted `URL` looks like this where the parameter `uri` is still different:

```
http://www.example.com/english/404.php?uri=somedata
```

or with another language:

```
http://www.example.com/german/404.php?uri=somedata
```

The code of `/english/404.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
session_start();
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

include_once "../scripts/db_connect.php";
include_once "../scripts/functions.php";
include_once "../scripts/browser_identification.php";
include_once "../scripts/pref_language.php";

...some text variables in its specific language

include_once "../templates/template_404.php";
?>
```

The template is just some HTML styling. The Footer that will be included in the `template_404.php` is the main attraction to send data. In that Footer there is the option to change the language setting and switching between the language paths. If a form will be submitted the `SESSION` and `COOKIE` will be changed and the page starts a header-function.

So here is the Code from the Footer:

```
if (isset($_GET['uri']) ) {
    $uri = urlencode($_GET['uri']);
    echo "TEST URI: $uri";
}

...

$basename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php"); 

if ($basename === "index") {
    $form_action = rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php');
} else{
    $form_action = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

...

if ( isset($_POST['pref_lang']) ) {

    $content = $_POST['pref_lang'];

    if ($content === "german") {

        if ($basename === "about") {
            $basename = "info";
        } else if ($basename === "contact") {
            $basename = "kontakt";
        }           
    }
    $_SESSION['pref_language'] = $_POST['pref_lang'];

    setcookie('pref_language', '', time()- 999999, '/', '.example.de' );
    setcookie('pref_language', $content, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', '.example.de');

    if ($basename === "404"){

        header("Location: ../$content/404.php?uri=$uri");

    } else {

        header("Location: ../$content/$basename");  
    }
}
?>
<div id="data">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <form action="<?php echo $form_action;?>" method="post">      
                    <input type="submit" id="german" name="pref_lang" value="german"/><label for="german">german</label>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The problem is that when a page has the `URL` of

```
http://www.example.com/**english**/404.php?uri=somedata
```

and I will submit `$_POST` to change the language to german like:

```
http://www.example.com/**german**/404.php?uri=somedata
```

for example `$_GET['uri']` will be empty and the `URL` looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/**german**/404.php?uri=
```

after starting header function. Instead of header I tried to echo out that line and I will receive a message that `uri` is not defined.

```
Undefined variable: uri in /customers/7/4/1/example.com/httpd.www/scripts/footer_en.php on line 102
Location: ../english/404.php?uri=
```

The strange about that is that when I will call the page before sending `$_POST` and have a look at the source code of the site the variable `$uri` will read out the `$_GET` parameter correctly but later on it does not work anymore in the header function. The question is why does that not work in that?

So it would be nice if someone can tell me what to do to fetch this issue. I really would appreciate.

Thanks alot.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to save the `$_GET` parameter into a `SESSION` but when posting the form and getting redirected to the other language site the content of the `SESSION` seems to be wrong because it will not be the `$_GET` parameter instead of that it will be something what comes from a css link from the html head like `css/colorbox.css`

At the moment I try to fetch this by setting the `form action` to that:

```
...
if ($basename === "index") {
    $form_action = rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php');
}  

if ($basename === "404") {
    $form_action = "";
}

if  ($basename !== "index" AND $basename !== "404") {
    $form_action = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
...

<li>
    <form action="<?php echo $form_action. ( (isset($_GET['uri']) ) ? "/english/?uri=".urlencode($_GET['uri']) : "" );?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" id="english" name="pref_lang" value="en"/><label for="en">englisch</label>
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: The GET will dissapear because after submitting the page will refresh and no GET parameter is given. You could store it in a session variable?

Comment: To be quite honest: TL;DR. But what's rather obvious to me is that you need to URL-encode the values correctly before appending it again as a query parameter. Values in `$_GET` are automatically URL *decoded* already. See http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding

Comment: @Marijke when I will do it by SESSION the content of that is a completety other than it should be. for some reason the session will be something like css/colorbox.css ... this is something what I do not understand.

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the language specific 404 template? Doesn't  [`include`](http://php.net/include) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to go from:

```
http://www.example.com/**english**/404.php?uri=somedata
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/**german**/404.php?uri=somedata
```

Using a form submit button. To do this you would set the action on the  tag to include the uri from the current page so that it's passed to the new language 404 page.

```
<form action="<?php echo $form_action . ((isset($_GET['uri']))?$_GET['uri']:""); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. i tried using your method, but it didnt work as i aspected. i updated my question. thanks.

Comment: Perhaps post the url that the above code created so that I can adjust it?

Comment: okay, your code creates that url: `http://www.example.com/english/404.php/english/404`

Comment: It seems like your code just replaces the `$_GET` parameter in case that is set. In case of changing your code to this: `<form action="<?php echo $form_action . ( (isset($_GET['uri']) ) ? "?uri=".$_GET['uri'] : "" ); ?>" method="post">` it seems like the `root/404.php` will be called and the `URL` is just: `http://www.example.com/english/404`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on jwheel12's answer. The form action will work as a relative path without http:// in it. Therefore appending your action="" to the current URL. Use an absolute path if possible.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/english/404.php<?php echo ( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] )?
"?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) : "" );?>" method="post">
```

or alternatively you could pass the variables as a hidden input type

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value"'.$value.'">';
}
```

I like to use a custom function like the one below that will loop through all the items in the array "$ary" and return the last one that is not empty.

```
$myVariable = getVar('myVariable');

function getVar($var) {
$ary = array('_SESSION', '_COOKIE', '_POST', '_GET');
foreach ($ary as $a) {
    if ($GLOBALS[$a][$var] != '') {
        $return = $GLOBALS[$a][$var];
    };
};
return $return;
};
```

Finally you could use preg_replace with a hyper link if you just want to toggle between 2 languages

```
$currentURL = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if (preg_match('/german/i', $currentURL)){
$newURL = preg_replace('/german/i', 'english',$currentURL);
$currentLanguage = "german";
}
else {
$newURL = preg_replace('/english/i', 'german',$currentURL);
$currentLanguage = "english";
};
echo '<a href ="'.$newURL. '">'($currentLanguage == "german"? "View in English": "Sehen Sie auf Deutsch";). '</a>';
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. i used your hints to fetch this but still have a small problem. when i will post the form the right language will be displayed but the footer itself will be the wrong one. the changes on session/cookie takes effect so i guess the site will be reloaded but the footer wont be. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
Note:

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Additionally, I believe http:// is required for FireFox and other HTTP 1.1 complaint browsers.

Perhaps try something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to stay on the same page, but have the content change?
if the language is english, load the english 404 info, for german load the german, etc.

Just a thought. I can imagine that it might not be practical for larger sites.